# How to style different elements of jquery ui differently?

Tags: css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-ui-autocomplete, jquery-ui-theme

To style the jqueryui tabs in a particular way, my team members modified the class ui-state-default as follows

```
.ui-state-default, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-default 
{ border: 3px solid transparent; 
  background: #F5AD4C 0px 0px repeat-x url(pix/redesign/orangebuttonstrip.jpg); 

  font-weight: bold; color: White;  }
```

The problem now is that I am using jqueryui autocomplete combobox which creates a button element with the same class

Thus I have a the background image appearing which makes it look ugly and huge.

How do I set different styles for different elements? I tried puttin button.ui-state-default as a different style by jqueryui overrides that.

Comment: Doesn't look like they are using any of the above classes, apart from `.ui-widget-content`, for [autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#theming)? Can you create an example on jsFiddle?

Comment: I am using http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox .  If you inspect the dropdown button on that page you will see this <button type="button" tabindex="-1" title="Show All Items" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-icon-only ui-corner-right ui-button-icon" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span><span class="ui-button-text">&nbsp;</span></button>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your current CSS rules for tabs as follows:

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav .ui-state-default, 
.ui-tabs.ui-widget-content .ui-state-default, 
.ui-tabs .ui-widget-header .ui-state-default { border: 3px solid transparent; 
  background: #F5AD4C 0px 0px repeat-x url(pix/redesign/orangebuttonstrip.jpg);
  font-weight: bold; color: White;
}
```

*Note*: `.ui-tabs.ui-widget-content` is not an error, it's like that on purpose. It means if both of those classes are present, then style by the rule that follows.

Comment: No this doesnt seem to work. While debuggin in firebug I notice that the same classes that you mentioned above for tabs are applied to the button. Why do you think that is happening?

Comment: @sassyboy: If you can't create an example for me to debug I can't tell you exactly what is going on. The lower classes might be applied, but `ui-tabs` will not, thus the above rules should not be applied to the button.

Comment: Could you just help me clear the fundamentals of how this type of style definition works over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7400821/what-does-multiple-class-definition-mean-and-how-is-it-supposed-to-work Will make it easier for me to debug if I have a better understanding of how this is supposed to work.

Comment: @sassyboy: I gave you a detailed explanation, I hope that helps you grasp it.

Comment: What was missing from the above was that there needed to a be .ui-tabs-nav in between .ui-tabs and .ui-state-default for the thing to work the way I wanted it. But the answer was in the right direction so I marked it as answer! Thanks for your help!