# What does multiple class definition mean and how is it supposed to work?

Tags: css, jquery-ui, css-selectors

I am trying to debug a jqueryui css issue which has led me to this question -

We find that in jqueryui css, there are class definitions such as follows :

```
.ui-state-default, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-default 
    { border: 3px solid transparent; background: #FFF 0px 0px; font-weight: bold; color: White;  }
```

Now, notice there is no comma between ui-widget-content and  ui-state-default. What does this class definition mean?

if I define .ui-button .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default should it override the above definition if a .ui-button actually precedes the others in the class attribute of the element?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is the hierarchical selector.

```
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-default
```

Means select all those child elements with the class `ui-state-default` whose parent has the class `ui-widget-content`.

---

I am writing an example for you to grasp it by [**seeing it in action**](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/XWPPK/).

#### 1. Markup

```
<div class="ui-tabs">
    <div class="ui-widget-content">
        <div class="ui-state-default"></div>
        <div class="ui-state-default"></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="ui-button">
    <div class="ui-widget-content">
        <div class="ui-state-default"></div>
        <div class="ui-state-default"></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### 2. CSS

```
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-default{
    background-color: red;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}

.ui-button .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default{
    background-color: green;
    border: 3px dashed yellow;
}
```

#### 3. Explanation

All `DIV`s with the class `ui-state-default` that have a parent with the class `ui-widget-content` will have applied all the properties of the first CSS rule, except those `DIV`s whose parent has the class `ui-parent`, whose `background-color` rule will be overwritten.